# Search Similar value in json

Tags: javascript, json

when i am using fetch i am getting data in json format. I want to search json via cust_id and return only matching record. please tell me how to do it. I have to show all the credit card the person have.

```
"objects": [
    {
        "card_number": "123412341234",
        "created_at": "2018-10-06T06:02:25.053942",
        "cust_id": "12345",
        "id": 1,
        "resource_uri": "/api/card/1/",
        "status": "completed"
    },
    {
        "card_number": "213412345678",
        "created_at": "2018-10-06T06:53:22.588967",
        "cust_id": "12345",
        "id": 3,
        "resource_uri": "/api/card/3/",
        "status": "pending"
    },

]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps

```
var val={
    "objects": [
        {
            "card_number": "123412341234",
            "created_at": "2018-10-06T06:02:25.053942",
            "cust_id": "12345",
            "id": 1,
            "resource_uri": "/api/card/1/",
            "status": "completed"
        },
        {
            "card_number": "213412345678",
            "created_at": "2018-10-06T06:53:22.588967",
            "cust_id": "12345",
            "id": 3,
            "resource_uri": "/api/card/3/",
            "status": "pending"
        },

    ] 
};


function get(val,custid){
    var result;
    for(var i=0;i<val.objects.length;i++){
        if(val.objects[i].cust_id=custid){
            result= val.objects[i];
        }  
    }     
    return result;
}
console.log(get(val,"1235"));
```

For multiple records you can take result as array and use array.push to insert in result (function variable) and return the array in end

Answer (score 0):

```js
var objects= [
    {
        "card_number": "123412341234",
        "created_at": "2018-10-06T06:02:25.053942",
        "cust_id": "12345",
        "id": 1,
        "resource_uri": "/api/card/1/",
        "status": "completed"
    },
    {
        "card_number": "213412345678",
        "created_at": "2018-10-06T06:53:22.588967",
        "cust_id": "12345",
        "id": 3,
        "resource_uri": "/api/card/3/",
        "status": "pending"
    },
 {
        "card_number": "213412345678",
        "created_at": "2018-10-06T06:53:22.588967",
        "cust_id": "12345",
        "id": 3,
        "resource_uri": "/api/card/3/",
        "status": "pending"
    },

]



console.log(objects.filter(i=>i['cust_id'] === '12345'))
```

Comment: thanks guys really appreciate :)